# is there a way to read a specific line of data from a file and split the numbers into single lists

Tags: c#, parsing

List item

I have a data file like:

JOB NAME ADMINISTRATION BUILDING JOB CLIENT MODA JOB NO E830-2-01-S-01 ENGINEER NAME MA CHECKER NAME MHI END JOB INFORMATION INPUT WIDTH 79 UNIT METER KN JOINT COORDINATES 1 32.15 0 -2; 2 34.81 0 -2; 3 37.47 0 -2; 4 40.13 0 -2; 5 32.15 2 -2; 6 34.81 2 -2; 7 37.47 2 -2; 8 40.13 2 -2; 9 0 0 0; 10 3 0 0; 11 7 0 0; 12 11 0 0; 13 15.1 0 0; 14 19 0 0; 15 23.1 0 0; 16 27.2 0 0; 17 30.15 0 0; 18 42.13 0 0; 19 0 2 0; 20 3 2 0; 21 7 2 0; 22 11 2 0; 23 15.1 2 0; 24 19 2 0; 25 23.1 2 0; 26 27.2 2 0; 27 30.15 2 0; 28 42.13 2 0; 31 15.1 2 0.95; 32 19 2 0.95; 33 42.13 0 2.66; 34 42.13 2 2.66; 35 0 0 4; 37 3 0 4; 38 7 0 4; 39 11 0 4; 40 15.1 0 4; 41 19 0 4; 42 23.1 0 4; 43 27.2 0 4; 44 30.15 0 4; 45 34 0 4; 46 0 2 4; 47 1.05 2 4; 48 3 2 4; 49 7 2 4; 50 11 2 4; 51 15.1 2 4; 52 19 2 4; 53 23.1 2 4; 54 27.2 2 4; 55 30.15 2 4; 56 34 2 4; 57 42.13 0 5.32; 58 42.13 2 5.32; 59 0 0 6; 61 3 0 6; 62 7 0 6; 63 11 0 6; 64 15.1 0 6;

in this I want to take values after the string "JOINT COORDINATES", and store each semicolon separated sets of number into four lists like : if 1 32.15 0 -2;2 34.81 0 -2 etc and split the numbers and store them different lists.

I am able to read upto "JOINT COORDINATES" and now not able to read from next line and split and store the numbers. please help.

```
var nodeInfo_List = new List<string[]>();
var nodeID_List = new List<double[]>();
var nodeX_List = new List<double[]>();
var nodeY_List = new List<double[]>();
var nodeZ_List = new List<double[]>();
StreamReader myfile = new StreamReader(@"D:\Documents\PIP_Task\PB_devTask\PB_devTask\ADMIN PHASE 2-a3.std");
//string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"D:\Documents\PIP_Task\PB_devTask\PB_devTask\ADMIN PHASE 2-a3.std");
string[] lines;
do
{
    lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"D:\Documents\PIP_Task\PB_devTask\PB_devTask\ADMIN PHASE 2-a3.std");
    if (lines != null)
    {
        //iterate through lines
        foreach (var name in lines)
        {
            if(name.Equals("JOINT COORDINATES"))
            {
                var nums = myfile.ReadLine();
                if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(nums))
                {
                    nodeInfo_List.Add(nums.Split(';'));
                    foreach (var node in nodeInfo_List)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("{0}: ", node);
                    }

                }
            }
        }

    }
} while (lines != null);
```

Comment: Can you give example, how you want to store numbers?

Comment: This may be a dumb question, but I'm seeing that you first open the file in stream reader and then read all of the contents of the file, and then try to reread a line in the loop.  Is there a reason that's needed?

Comment: You have posted 2 rows here in the question?

Comment: actually all the above strings are in separate lines, so the if condition is satisfied. what I want is after the if is true it must split as per the ';' and store the four numbers in four list for all such set of four numbers

Comment: and i want to store 1st nums of all sets in NodeID_List and the three in the nodeX_List , nodeY_List , nodeZ_List respectively

Comment: Can you organize your input accordingly in the question.

Comment: I don't get why you would need ReadAllLines and StreamReader at the same time! ReadAllLines alone would do the job just fine.

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me a simple split by specify you string and then take the first array , split by ";".

```
var inputArr = inputString.Split(new[] { "JOINT COORDINATES" },  
 StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
var coordinates = inputArr[1].Split(';');
```

I hope I am not missing any point here.

Comment: this is super easy and i would have never trought of that.

Answer (score 1):

hi one problem is after you find the row that matches the "JOINT COORDINATES" string 
you try to read line from the file while the pointer of my myfile is in the first line .
try the follow approach

```
var nodeInfo_List = new List<string[]>();
        var nodeID_List = new List<double[]>();
        var nodeX_List = new List<double[]>();
        var nodeY_List = new List<double[]>();
        var nodeZ_List = new List<double[]>();
        StreamReader myfile = new StreamReader(@"D:\Documents\PIP_Task\PB_devTask\PB_devTask\ADMIN PHASE 2-a3.std");


  string line;
        do
        {
            line = myfile.ReadLine();
        } while (!line.Equals("JOINT COORDINATES"));

            do
            {
                var nums = myfile.ReadLine();
                if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(nums))
                {
                    nodeInfo_List.Add(nums.Split(';'));
                    foreach (var node in nodeInfo_List)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("{0}: ", node);
                    }
                }
            } while (!myfile.EndOfStream);
```